# Is there an API to close Session in Neo4j-ogm?

Tags: java, spring, session, neo4j, neo4j-ogm

I am using neo4j-ogm 1.1.4 version. 
Since I use the org.springframework.data.neo4j.template.Neo4jTemplate which I create by myself using the session object, I am wondering is there a contract that once all my work is done, then I have to mark the session closed.

I came across this link

http://inner-loop.github.io/java-neo4j-ogm/

But the library I am using seems to have no close method on the Session class. Is there any other API I need to use to mark the session closed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is technically no need to "close" the Session in the Neo4j OGM. It does not represent a connection to the database, instead it maintains conversational state between your application and the database, allowing the OGM to generate efficient Cypher when you load and save objects within a "unit of work" (as defined by your application).

There are two ways to destroy this conversational state. They both have the same effect from the perspective of your application code.

**reuse**

`session.clear()` allows you to reuse the existing session object by deleting the existing conversational state.

**replace**

`session = sessionFactory.openSession()` will replace any current `session` object with a new one.

Both these operations will leave the OGM with no information about the synchronisation state of your domain objects vis-a-vis the graph. (In Hibernate terms, they are in a 'detached' state) The OGM currently has no mechanism to re-attach your domain objects to a new session, so you should *always* reload all the objects you want to use into the new session.

Comment: so I can just create a session in a function, use it and let the java gc take care of it?

Answer (score 0):

I had a requirement to handle multiples database connections in my backend. So I implemented a `SPRING BOOT` unbounded pool that "works". This handles the `clear` mentioned in the @Vince answer;

```java
@Component
public class Neo4jOGMSessionPool implements ApplicationListener<RequestHandledEvent> {

  private @Value("${neo4j.uri}") String uri;
  private @Value("${neo4j.username}") String username;
  private @Value("${neo4j.password}") String password;

  private final Map<String, LinkedBlockingQueue<Session>> queues = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
  private final ThreadLocal<Entry<String, Session>> threadLocal = new ThreadLocal<>();

  public synchronized Session getSession(String databaseName) {
    LinkedBlockingQueue<Session> queue = queues.computeIfAbsent(databaseName, k -> new LinkedBlockingQueue<>());
    Session session = queue.poll();
    if (session == null) {
      Configuration configuration = new Configuration.Builder().uri(uri).credentials(username, password).database(databaseName).verifyConnection(true).build();
      SessionFactory sessionFactory = new SessionFactory(configuration, "no.package");
      session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    }
    threadLocal.set(Maps.immutableEntry(databaseName, session));
    return session;
  }

  @Override
  public void onApplicationEvent(RequestHandledEvent event) {
    Entry<String, Session> entry = threadLocal.get();
    if (entry != null) {
      Session session = entry.getValue();
      session.clear();
      threadLocal.remove();
      queues.get(entry.getKey()).add(session);
    }
  }

}
```